# Categorical data treatment courses

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, descriptive-statistics, categorical-encoding, exploratory-data-analysis

Is there a book or online course/mooc related to the treatment of categorical data? I have seen this course as an elective in my university in the Statistics degree, and also as a core course in a Stats Master of Science, but had no luck searching for material related to that topic yet, besides some blogs on Analytics Vidhya or Towards Data Science / Medium.

I know it's a wide topic that often depends on the knowledge or business domain we are applying it to, but I'm looking for at least some kind of formal training on the matter.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there are dedicated courses but
[Alan Agresti](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Eaa/)'s book [An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Categorical+Data+Analysis%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9781119405269) is a good starting point. However, new developments in deep learning such as `cat2vec` is unlikely to be covered there [Cat2Vec: Learning Distributed Representation of Multi-field Categorical Data](https://openreview.net/forum?id=HyNxRZ9xg).

Of course R's `vcd` package's vignette would be helpful too :[vcd Tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcdExtra/vignettes/vcd-tutorial.pdf) and pandas's manual on [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).